# set value for java variable from javascript function

Tags: java, javascript

I have a aui select field(drop-down), & I want to perform some operation if drop-down option changes.

So my aui select field shows like this:

```
<form action="<liferay-portlet:actionURL name="saveInfo" />"

    <aui:select name="selectAmount" inlineLabel="true" label="select-amount" onChange="performOperationsOnInputField()">
        <aui:option value="0"></aui:option>
        <aui:option value="1">1</aui:option>
        <aui:option value="2">2</aui:option>
        <aui:option value="3">3</aui:option>
        <aui:option value="4">4</aui:option>
        <aui:option value="5">5</aui:option>
    </aui:select>

</form>
```

and script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function performOperationsOnInputField() {
         var portletNamespace = '<portlet:namespace />';
         var selectedValue = $('#selectAmount').val();

         if(selectedValue == '0') {
            // set a java variable value which can be access fro any java file(like static variable) or any best way so that we can access it from any java/jsp file

            });                   
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Can we set a java variable value from script so that we can access value of this fields globally from any java file & from any jsp page?

Answer (score 1):

> // set a java variable value which can be access fro any java file(like static variable) or any best way so that we can access it from any java/jsp file

**No you cannot.**

You might misunderstand that `JSP` and `JavaScript` existed on same document. Yes but `JSP` part compiles on server side itself comes to `client`.

`Javascript` Plays on client side and `JSP` plays on server side.

What you need to do is you have to make a `server` request. And send that string as a `query` parameter or form or `Ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

doing an ajax based call to server will pass your data from java-script to java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax based call and can pass the values by appending into queryString